# Prove $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{p}-1}$ converges, where $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis

This is probably a very basic question but I have tried my best and still cannot solve it. I tried the comparison test against the p-series and also cauchy-condesation test, but none seems to work.

Comment: For convergence, this is effectively the same as $\sum \frac 1{n^p}$.    Prove, say, that $\frac 1{n^p-1}<\frac 2{n^p}$.  Note:  you need $n>1$.

Comment: Refer to [LCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Answer (score 0):

The series behaves as $\sum \frac1{x^p}$, to prove that rigoursly we can use limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{x^p}$ indeed

$$\frac{\frac1{x^p-1}}{\frac1{x^p}}=\frac{x^p}{x^p-1}\to 1$$

Note that also Cauchy condensation test works indeed

$$\sum a_{2^k}= \sum \frac{2^k}{2^{pk}-1}$$

which converges since $\frac{2^k}{2^{pk}-1} \sim\frac1{2^{k(p-1)}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with the direct comparison test since 
$$
\frac{1}{n^p}<\frac{1}{n^p-1}<\frac{2}{n^p}
$$
when $n^p>2$.

For the lower inequality, $n^p>n^p-1$, so $\frac{1}{n^p-1}>\frac{1}{n^p}$.

For the upper inequality, in this case, $n^p-2>0$ so $2n^p-2>n^p$, or, in other words, $2(n^p-1)>n^p$.  Therefore, $\frac{2}{n^p}>\frac{1}{n^p-1}$.

Therefore, $\frac{1}{n^p}$ and $\frac{1}{n^p-1}$ converge or diverge together.